# What is static file materialization in Magento 2 and the difference with static views?

Tags: magento2, cache, indexing

Just had a confusion with some of the concepts in Magento 2. What is static file materialization means in Magento 2 and wanted to know its different with static views ?

It will be great if someone can explain both concepts and the difference as I didn't find enough resources to explain what exactly "static file materialization" means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Static file materialization** is the action of writing **static view files** to the Magento file system.

Static means cached, understand the file is not dynamically generated.

View means the view/presentation layer from MVC.

You can find the static view files under `/pub/static` folder and some of them are cached under the `/var/view_preprocessed` folder.

You can get more details in the official documentation: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html