# Magento 2: Is deploying static content necessary in developer mode?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, static-content, developer-mode

Some threads say compilation is not necessary in developer mode, what about `static-content:deploy`? When I working on magento 2 modules, I often have problems getting my changes updated in the front end, I sort of leaned to clear different types of cache, generated files and static files, but **I'm not sure whether deploy static content is necessary in developer mode.** Any comments would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: First remove pub/static content and you need to run deploy command otherwise your changes are not apperar and all files inside pub/static are not updated.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, Run deploy command is necessary for developer mode for below cases.

When you install any new extension you need to define deployment command when module contains any custom web/js folder and web/template static file if you cant run deploy command you have to see many js error inside console.

**When you need to customized on module web js folder content** at that time you need to run deploy command to get effect of changes in frontend.

In most cases, when you customize `module/view/{area}/web/js/` and `module/view/{area}/web/template/` file at that time you must need to run deploy command to see changes on your area. Here area is frontend or admin.

Comment: Thanks for your insight, that's really helpful because a lot of times when I clear all cache even static content updates are still not appearing in the front end. I haven't done any js customisation, mainly layout and template and I do notice in most cases clear cache and var/generation do the trick, while other times they drive me nuts. Magento 2 has a very stiff learning curve.

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara  have you remove var folder and run deploy command, also remove browser cache to see affect

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara, go to cmd and go your project root, now run command php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy, Before run deploy command you need to remove pub/static and root var folder

Answer (score 0):

No, **in developer mode, static file materialization is not enabled**. Thus, static view files are generated every time they are requested. They are written to the `pub/static` directory, but this cache is not used. This has big performance impact, but any changes a developer makes to view files are immediately visible. I reckon the problems you're facing are more related to the interceptors, where `var/generation` needs to be flushed when changing classes constructors.

Btw, you can learn more about the different modes here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/111708/2380

Comment: Hi, when any web/js or web/template static file need to customize at that time we need to run deploy command to see chagnes, Right?

Comment: @Rakesh if you're in production mode yes: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html

Comment: but when we changes on web/js folder its not get changes directly when we refrresh front, after run deploy its take effect on front in developer mode also

Comment: @Rakesh you're probably not in developer mode then. Or you have permissions issues

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism what does "Static file Materialization" mean? Sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: @EthanWan http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/111723/2380 ;)

Comment: I do notice in developer mode, all files in pub/static get generated only after they get removed; otherwise they stay the same. When I first started my project I followed Alan Storm's guide to use pub as my magento root. Will this be the issue when I running in developer mode?

Comment: @EthanWan well it's hard to say. If you have `pub/static/.htaccess` Magento will create symlinks for the static files on the fly. Maybe you don't have the right permissions on your files ?

Comment: Here is what I use for to set my file permission:

`find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc var -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \;`
`find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc var -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \;`
I do have .htaccess file in `pub/static`, what permission should I use for .htaccess?

Comment: Why the downvote though ?

Comment: @Raphael at Digital Pianism Sorry that wasn't me as I'm still a newbie not eligible for voting YET, I tried up vote your answer as I think it make sense to me, but the voting didn't work.